# Is web services API and API usage the same?

Tags: community, api

I am using the professional edition of salesforce and we have brought the web services api. Is the Web services api and Api usage the same ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have enabled the API for the professional edition ,anything making call to salesforce from external system will count against API limit excluding the outbound messages and the Apex Callout .

Web Services API corresponds to simply API and depending on your licence edition you will have limits on number of API calls for your organization

Comment: So If we remove the feature of web services API. would that make the usage of the app exchange products not functional ?